# C comma is breaking integer in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

The code below asks the user to enter a number followed by an operator. It works as long as no commas are used.  For example,

Happy path

```
6000+2000 will output 6000.000 + 2000.000
```

Unexpected output

```
6,000+2,000 will output 6.000 , 0.000
```

Can *scanf* somehow treat the value as float when using a comma?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char operatorFound;
    float num1,num2, calcValue;
    printf("Please enter a simple expression (ie: 2+2):" );
    scanf("%f%c%f", &num1, &operatorFound, &num2);
    printf("%f\n%c\n%f", num1, operatorFound, num2); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` isn't going to do anything for you. You're stuck reading in lines, performing a pass to check format and/or fix up the string, then use `sscanf` to parse the fixed string.

Comment: Yes, commas will break integer fields in `scanf`.  If you want to parse integer formats that include separator commas then you need something else, or at least something extra.

Comment: Change _locale_, `scanf()`, restore _locale_

Comment: In your country (or the country (locale) set in your machine) it is expected a dot as decimal point and a comma as separator. In some other countries, like Germany, it is common to do the other way around. As this is clearly a user interface, it should be in the locale of the user, not the developer, therefore scanf is doing a great job.

Answer (score 4):

It may be possible to adjust scanf under Linux by setting the locale accordingly. See [scanf Linux documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

> For decimal conversions, an optional quote character (').
> This specifies that the input number may include
> thousands' separators as defined by the LC_NUMERIC
> category of the current locale.  (See setlocale(3).)  The
> quote character may precede or follow the '*' assignment-
> suppression character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char operatorFound;
    float num1, num2, calcValue;
    // Use en_US.UTF-8 to separate groups of thousands, many other countries use a period instead, and some countries separate thousands groups with a space
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US.UTF-8");
    puts("Please enter a simple expression (ie: 2+2):" );
    
    // Notice the use of a single quote
    if (scanf("%'f %c%'f", &num1, &operatorFound, &num2) == 3) { 
        printf("%f\n%c\n%f", num1, operatorFound, num2); 
    } else {
        puts("Unable to process input");
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: May also suggest `"%'f %c%'f"` to accommodate whitespace surrounding the operator.

Comment: quote character (') is a non-standard C extension for `*scanf()`.  Not in C17, C11, etc.

Comment: Just looked that up, not ISO C, [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2)

Comment: Tried it it didn't work form me. Still the same thing

Comment: @JoseOrtiz Be sure to set the locale accordingly. See setlocale for more info.

Comment: I think the question wasn't formatted correctly. I want to ask a user to enter number1 operator number2 then with a switch statement determine which math operation it is. If the enduser puts 6000 + 2000 it would read what they put in and determine its addition and output the answer. If the user puts 6,000 + 2,000 it does not find the operator since it thinks the comma is the character string. so it output 6.000 , 0.000 and state that the operation is unknown.

Comment: @JoseOrtiz That's easy, see https://onlinegdb.com/S1-OQOfVu

Comment: it always goes to  unable to process input

Comment: @JoseOrtiz you are probably using spaces. Try with the modified scanf https://onlinegdb.com/SJuaeTXEu

Comment: I copied your code and tested with space without space and its the same unable to process input

Comment: I think my compiler doesn't like setlocale. Also what if the user does enter space between the numbers and the operator how could we handle that

Comment: yup its my compiler I tried with linux gcc and it works

Answer (score 0):

While you are scanning the input C takes commas as char.

If you enter only 6,00 it will still print 6.000 , 0.000 because it takes comma as a second input.

Therefore you should use dots '.' for floats

Answer (score -1):

So after testing. I found out my compiler is flawed. When I test on Linux GCC all the answers worked.

If I enter

6,000 + 2,000 it will output 8000

6000 + 2000 it will output 8000

6,000 + 2000 it will output 8000

6000 + 2,000 it will output 8000

6000+2000 it will output 8000

etc etc

Thank you all for looking into this and helping me out

Comment: it's not flawed. The compiler has nothing to do with this because `printf` belongs to the C standard library which is completely separate from the compiler. And it's simply because your locale uses `,` as thousand separator so `6,000` is the same as `6000`. Use the C locale instead